# Enable and Disable array of textBoxes by Dynamic check boxes

Tags: php, jquery

I have some dynamic checkboxes and corresponding dynamic textboxes.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>   

<td><input type="checkbox" class="album_checkbox" id="phone[]" name="phone[]" value="<?=$row['mobile_no']?>" > </td>    
<td>
 <input type="text" class="album_text"  id="txt1[]" name="txt1[]" style="width: 15em" value="<?=$row['name']?>" disabled="disabled"> 
</td>
```

When a user ticks a checkbox and enters data into the corresponding textbox and submits, the value of the checkbox and textbox should be inserted into the database. I can insert the checkbox values perfectly, but the textbox values have issues.

```
 while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($dec)) {
    list ($key,$val2) = @each ($varv);
```

That code will only input the ticked checkbox values perfectly, but if i've ticked checkbox 1, 3 and 5 (of the dynamic checkboxes) it loops 3 times and will only insert values from TEXTBOX 1,2,3 INSTEAD OF 1, 3, 5.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Please provide php code for the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.album_checkbox').click(function(){

       $(this).closest('td').next('td').children('input').attr('disabled',!this.checked)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set disabled property of textbox based on checkbox values:

```
$('.album_checkbox').click(function () {
            if (!this.checked)
                $(this).closest('td').next('td').children('input').attr('disabled', "disabled");
            else
                $(this).closest('td').next('td').children('input').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```